# Using simple OpenCV code but get no output

Tags: python, image, opencv

Im using Visual Studio and Windows 10. The code gives no error, but gives no output either.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img_raw = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\zach5\OneDrive\Documents\Kivy_Projects\IMG_20210106_152434.png')

type(img_raw)
np.ndarray

img_raw.shape
(1300, 1950, 3)

plt.imshow(img_raw)
```

I don't know what is wrong, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add `plt.show()` at the end of your code

Comment: Sorry, I had not notice the answers when I posted my comment.

Comment: @RufusVS The truth is, I didn't see the comment when I posted my answer. Even if otherwise, answers should not be posted in the comments section, as comments are temporary.

Comment: @fmw42 You should not be sorry.  Your "solution" comment preceded the answers according to the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add `plt.show()` at the end:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img_raw = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\zach5\OneDrive\Documents\Kivy_Projects\IMG_20210106_152434.png')

plt.imshow(img_raw)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are importing plot from matplotlib and by using

```
   plt.imshow(img_raw)
```

you are plotting in on a plot but you always need to explicitly specify to show it on gui by using

```
  plt.show()
```

that makes the plot visible on gui